# Vectorize a simple function in python: avoid double for loop

Tags: python

I'm completely new to python. I'm trying to do a very simple thing, evaluate a non-trivial function that takes floats as input on a 2D mesh. The following code does exactly what I want, but it is slow, due to the double for loop.

```
import numpy as np
from galpy.potential import RazorThinExponentialDiskPotential


R = np.logspace(0., 2., 10)
z=R

#initialize with default values for this example
potfunc=RazorThinExponentialDiskPotential()

pot=np.zeros((R.size, z.size))


for i in range(0, R.size):
    for j in range(0, z.size):
        pot[i,j]=potfunc(R[i],z[j])
```

At the end, the array pot contains all the information I want, but now I want to increase the efficency. I know that pure python is slow, expecially on loops (like IDL), so I checked np.vectorize, but it's just a python loop under the hood.
The problem is that potfunc seems not accepting arrays, but just plain scalars.

How can I optimize this simple program?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do that is using [`meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) :

```
  r,z=np.meshgrid(R,Z)
  pot=potfunc(r,z)
```

You must avoid looping on numpy array, or you will loose all vectorisation efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

In case you cannot vectorize the function by hand (maybe you could subclass the Razor.. class and rewrite the function), you could use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html). Instead of my simple worker function you could use the function you like.:

```
from multiprocessing import pool
import numpy as np
def worker(x):
    ai,bj = x
    return ai + bj

def run_pool():
    a = np.linspace(0,10,10)
    b = np.logspace(0,10,len(a))
    vec = [(a[i],b[j]) for i in range(len(a)) for j in range(len(b))]
    p = pool.Pool(processes=4) # as many cores as you have
    print(p.map(worker,vec))
    p.close()
    p.join()

run_pool()
```

But before you think about speeding things up, profiling would be good. I am pretty sure that in your case the function itself is the bottleneck. So either you rewrite it in a compiler language, vectorize it or you use all of your cores.